# java TableView getSelectedIndices() contains index of -1

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2

I have a problem using getSelectedIndices(). Occassionally, not always, as I have discovered in debug sessions in the database code, it returns an array that includes an index of -1.

Why is that so, and what could I do to prevent this? I want to use this style of logic is various places.

I have a Livestock TableView with SelectionMode.MULTIPLE.
It has a ContextMenu that includes ('Set Breed', 'Set Sex' and 'Set Has Calf')

The logic to set one of these attributes is the same:
The user will, (1) select the relevant rows (using  or  + mouse-click), then (2) select the relevant MenuItem

This will then invoke setLivestockAttribute() as follows:

```
private void setLivestockAttribute( String attribute )
{
    String value = "";

    // 1. Get a List of the Indices of Rows selected.
    ObservableList<Integer> selectedIndices = null;
    selectedIndices = FXCollections.observableList(tblView_Livestock.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndices());        

    // If ONE or MORE rows have been selected.
    if ( selectedIndices.size() > 0 )
    {
        // 2. Get the VALUE of the relevant ATTRIBUTE.
        switch (attribute) 
        {
            case LM_Constant.BREED:
                value = LM_Utility.getChoice_Breed();
                break;
            case LM_Constant.SEX:
                value = LM_Utility.getChoice_Sex();
                break;
            case LM_Constant.HAS_CALF:
                value = LM_Utility.getChoice_HasCalf();
                break;                    
        }

        // If there is a VALUE.
        if ( value.length() > 0 )
        {
            ObservableList<LivestockModel> dataList = tblView_Livestock.getItems();

            // 3. Update each Livestock record.
            DataStore.getInstance().updateLivestock(dataList, selectedIndices, attribute, value);

            // 4. Refresh the TableView to show changes.
            setLivestockData();    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What JRE/JDK version are you using? There was a similar bug that was fixed in one of the latest releases (8u101 or 8u111 IIRC)

Comment: Many thanks. (java -version

Comment: Version is 8u-60. Will ugrade soon at test. Many thanks. @sillyfly

Answer (score 1):

I have decided to:

- update the JDK ( as suggested by @sillyfly)
- adjust the code to avoid the error (see below)
- subscribe to Oracle to receive notices of future upgrades and bug fixes

Code segment ensures database update, ONLY when the index i >= 0.

```
public boolean updateLivestock(ObservableList<LivestockModel> livestockData, ObservableList<Integer> selectedIndices, String attribute, String value)
{
    boolean proceed = true;
    boolean updated = false;
    int rowCount = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    String sql = "";
    LivestockModel lm;

    switch (attribute) 
    {
        case LM_Constant.BREED:
            sql = "UPDATE livestock SET (breed, last_updated) = (?, DEFAULT) WHERE rfid = ? AND begin_event = ?";
            break;
        case LM_Constant.SEX:
            sql = "UPDATE livestock SET (sex, last_updated) = (?, DEFAULT) WHERE rfid = ? AND begin_event = ?";
            break;
        case LM_Constant.HAS_CALF:
            sql = "UPDATE livestock SET (has_calf, last_updated) = (?, DEFAULT) WHERE rfid = ? AND begin_event = ?";
            break;                
    }

    try ( PreparedStatement preparedUpdate = connection.prepareStatement(sql) )
    {            
        for (Integer i : selectedIndices)
        { 
            if ( proceed != true )
                break;

            if ( i >= 0 )
            {
                lm = livestockData.get(i);

                preparedUpdate.setString(1, value);
                preparedUpdate.setString(2, lm.getRFID());
                preparedUpdate.setInt(3, lm.getBeginEvent());

                rowCount = preparedUpdate.executeUpdate();
                if ( rowCount == 1 )
                    counter++;
            }
            else
            {
                counter++;
                LM_Utility.showError_Dialog("Update Livestock", "Index Error", "index = " + i.toString());
            }
        }

        if ( counter == selectedIndices.size() )
        {   
            connection.commit();               
            updated = true;   
        }

    }
    catch (SQLException sqle)
    {
        LM_Utility.showSQL_Exception("updateLivestock()", sqle); 
        proceed = false;
    }        

    return updated;
}
```

Comment: Yup, I see the same thing. My guess is that -1 is set while JavaFX is busy updating things. As far as I can tell ignoring the selected indices works fine.